# how to deal with international time?

Tags: java, jsp, timezone

i build a new website.but the host is in USA.i am not in USA.
i need get the time on the website page to compare with one local Variable.
But because of time difference,it has 8 hous difference。how to solve this problom?

my code

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
java.util.Date currentTime = new java.util.Date();  
String dateString = formatter.format(currentTime);  `
```

how to revise these code ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle timezones, Java includes the [Olson timezone database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Find the city in the database that is in the same time zone as you are.

First, you need to get a [`TimeZone` object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) for the timezone you want. Then, get a [`Calendar` object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) with the current date and time (or the date and time you wish to use). You can format that with a SimpleDateFormat object.

```
TimeZone local = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(local); // gets time in the current timezone
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(local)

String dateString = formatter.format(now.getTime());
```

Though if you're doing a lot of time manipulation, like Bozho says, go for joda-time. The Java date/time system is confusing and rather poorly designed.

Comment: i put u code in my jsp page...  but, it doesnt work. the time still same with my local time .. not "Asia/Tokyo" time.. why?

Comment: @alex It's because I neglected to set the timezone on the formatter; I've corrected that. Like I said, it's confusing and poorly-designed ;)

Comment: just a little wrong.. " formatter.setTimeZone(local);" thx~ everything is ok now. :P

Answer (score 6):

`java.util.Date` does not support timezones. You should pass the `TimeZone` to the formatter instead, by calling `formatter.setTimeZone(tz)`.

[joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is considered a better choice when working with dates. Note that for the sake of formatting it is fine to use `Date`, but it is a general advise not to rely on it when it comes to i18n. (Note the many deprecated methods there)

Then make each user set his timezone. Ideally suggest / assume the timezone based on his browser locale. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768007/how-to-detect-user-time-zone-in-sign-up-forms)

And always store the dates in a fixed timezone - preferably GMT/UTC.

Comment: +1 for storing times in GMT, but -1 for saying not to use `Date`.  There's nothing wrong with using `Date`, it just defines a point in time.  All you need to do is tell the formatter what `TimeZone` you want the dates formatting in.

Comment: @SimonC - it is not OK to use Date, because it uses the default timezome of the JVM. And while this is indeed fine for formatting (by using an external formatter), it was a general advise not to use it.

Comment: @Bozho why do you say it is not OK?  As long as you treat `Date` objects as simply a point in time since the epoch and use the correct timezone when dealing with calendars or formatting then you won't go wrong.  I.e. don't call `toString()` or any of the deprecated method like `getHours()`.

Comment: @SimonC - well, it is safe with a number of preconditions. And that's why it's tricky. The whole class hasn't been deprecated, so I agree it has its usecases, but might be tricky. Plus, it's mutable. All this has led to replacements like Calendar, `DateTime` and the upcoming standard datetime api.

Comment: i  put "  TimeZone local = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(local);  
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");       

String dateString = formatter.format(now.getTime());"

Comment: but, it doesnt work. the time still same with my local time .. not "Asia/Tokyo" time.. why?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I always [change timezone in Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Timezone-in-Linux):

```
mv /etc/localtime  /etc/localtime-backup
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime
```

It also can be helpful for reading log files for example (I always see my local time instead of calculating it each time when I need to dig into them)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a Calendar (they are more useful generally than just Date objects).  If you create a Calendar, initialised with your locale and timezone, you can do `calendar.setDate()` using the date you created.  If you create another Calendar object with the fields that were entered, you can then do comparisons between the two Calendar objects.

Comment: u say "create a Calendar, initialised with your locale and timezone",can u give me a code example ?

Comment: Sure, if you look at the docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#Calendar(java.util.TimeZone, java.util.Locale), you can construct a Calendar with your own timezone/locale.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, you can get an instance, for example: `  Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
`